# Running a .NET Core Console Application on Mac or Windows

Tags: c#, windows, macos, .net-core

I've created a .NET Core console application. I want to build the app so that I can execute it on Windows or MacOS without dotnet core being installed on the machine. So I need e.g. for windows an exe.

I've read https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-publish and I know how to compile the application for the different platform(s).

But no executable gets created. What am I missing here and how do I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need is to create a [self-contained application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/app-types#self-contained-application). The link explains how exactly to modify your project.json to do that.

Also note that while a self-contained application does not have a dependency on .Net Core, it may have other dependencies. Specifically on OSX, I believe you will need to install a specific version of openssl from homebrew.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to compile my project and execute it. Is there any way to remove to dlls i dont need? e.g. there is a Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.dll . I would like to have a smaller sized version. After publish i get a 46 MB folder for my little app :)

Comment: @dknaack [A coming version of .Net Core should handle that automatically.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/) For now, you can replace the dependency on `Microsoft.NETCore.App` with the dependencies that you actually need. For example, for a trivial Hello World app, the necessary dependencies seem to be `"Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR": "1.0.3",
"Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy": "1.0.1",
          "System.Console": "4.0.0"`.

Comment: Great! With you advice and http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/ i was able to archive my goal and cut the size by half.

Comment: Do you mind sharing how you executed your project on a mac, that you created on Windows? What command did you use?  All documentation I find explains how to publish but none shows how to run the portable freaking app on the mac.

Comment: @myfunnyfella To run a portable app that you've published, you use `dotnet yourapp.dll`.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Please edit the answer into the post.

Comment: @dknaack finally, you will be able to auto-prune it by adding this to your csproj if you're using .NET Core 3.0 Preview 6 or later: <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed> or via console add to your dotnet publish command /p:PublishTrimmed=true     (and of course need to do same for PublishSingleFile in either case)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing but my console application cannot access the file system (only executing with terminal and launching with sudo will work). There's a way to bypass this and let my application work normally? Thanks