# The debugger of Visual Studio for Mac always complains about "program does not exist"

Tags: macos, visual-studio, debugging

Running VS for Mac community 2017 (version 7.5.3 build 7) on High Sierra, with a .NET solution, the Release configuration runs OK.

But with the Debug configuration,

I always get the error `launch: Program "" does not exist.`

This is with a default template console application project, without any new code or tweaking.

The code `Program.cs` looks like:

```
using System;

namespace Hello
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

**UPDATE**

Within the solution folder on my Mac, there is no .exe generated. Cleaning and rebuilding the solution does not help.

[image]

Comment: Could you rebuild your app in your side? And then check your project output path. Make sure that whether it has the .exe file. Please also debug it using "start without debugging" in your side, view the result. Of course, set your project as the start up project firstly.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I updated my question. No there was no .exe generated on my mac.

Comment: If it is the .NET core console app in your side, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792042/running-a-net-core-console-application-on-mac-or-windows

Comment: Does it work if you create the self-contained application?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem with Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac on Mojave.

The reason the debug configuration does not run your program is due to a licensing restriction with the .NET Core debugger. It does not seem to be able to run the code through VS. I've included its informational log message below.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Some workarounds include:

- Run your .NET Core console app without the debugger (as you know)
- An `exe` is not generated for builds by default with the .NET Core solution template. Instead, run the DLL using your local `dotnet` executable with something like the following command.

  `$ /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet YOUR_PROGRAM.dll`
- Use the console app solution template that doesn't require .NET Core through the UI path: File > New Solution > Other > .NET > Console Project.

  In this case there is an `exe` and it can be run from the command with something like the following command.

  `$ /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/mono YOUR_PROGRAM.exe`